# Conditional Probabilities, babies using Bayes

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

There are $3$ boys and $x$ girls in a hopital (babies). A mother gives birth to a child but doesn't know it's gender. A midwife picks a random baby, given that she picked a boy, what is the probability it comes from the mother?

I used bayes, but I am struggling to specify (understand/make sense of) the probabilities.
Can someone please explain what each of the following probabilities are?

$$P(\text{Boy}\,|\,\text{Mother}),\, P(\text{Boy}),\, P(\text{Mother})$$

Comment: My guess: P(Mother) = P(The picked baby comes from the mother), P(Boy) = P(Midwife picks a boy), P(Boy | Mother) = P(It's a boy, given that the baby comes from the mother) = 1/2 (?). To find is P(Mother | Boy).

Comment: Thanks user66081, those probabilities make sense! :)

Comment: There is an uncertainty here: $3$ boys and $x$ girls in the baby's room --  before or after the new baby was born? It seems that it is obvious to everybody that "after" is the correct answer, is it?

Comment: no, 3 boys and x girls before, after there will be x+4 kids with an unknown number of boys (Note the answer is 1/7)

Comment: The probability that she is shown a boy is 3/(x + 4) if she had a girl, and 4/(x+4) if she had a boy - and therefore P(shown boy) = (1/2){3/(x + 4) +  4/(x+4) }.  The probability she had a boy and got shown her child is (1/2)(1/(x+4)).  The ratio between those is an answer I was surprised by

Answer (score 1):

With the information given and reading "There are $3$ boys and $x$ girls in a hospital" as the position after the mother has given birth, I would have thought the probabilities were independent, i.e.

- $P(\text{mother's child picked})= \dfrac{1}{3+x}$
- $P(\text{boy picked})= \dfrac{3}{3+x}$
- $P(\text{mother's child picked and it is a boy})= \dfrac{3}{(3+x)^2}$
- $P(\text{mother's child picked}\mid \text{boy picked})= \dfrac{1}{3+x}$
- $P(\text{boy picked}\mid \text{mother's child picked})= \dfrac{3}{3+x}$

*(Added later)*

If the "There are $3$ boys and $x$ girls in a hospital" is the position before the mother gives birth, then I would have said

- $P(\text{mother's child is a boy})= \dfrac{1}{2}$
- $P(\text{mother's child picked})= \dfrac{1}{4+x}$
- $P(\text{mother's child picked} \mid \text{mother's child is a boy})= \dfrac{1}{4+x}$
- $P(\text{boy picked} \mid \text{mother's child is a boy})= \dfrac{4}{4+x}$
- $P(\text{boy picked} \mid \text{mother's child is a girl})= \dfrac{3}{4+x}$
- $P(\text{boy picked})=\dfrac12 \dfrac{4}{4+x} + \dfrac12 \dfrac{3}{4+x} = \dfrac{7}{2(4+x)}$
- $P(\text{mother's child picked and it is a boy}) = \dfrac12 \dfrac{1}{4+x} = \dfrac{1}{2(4+x)}$
- $P(\text{mother's child picked} \mid \text{boy picked}) =  \dfrac{\frac{1}{2(4+x)}}{\frac{7}{2(4+x)}}= \dfrac{1}{7}$

which is the same as Cato's answer

Comment: is that a final answer or part working, you need the chance that it is the mother's baby boy handed to her - the 3/(3 + x) means that if there are a billion females, then it is probably not the mother's baby, however she had a boy with probability 1/2 (unaffected by the billion girls) - so in ~1/2 the cases, the baby shown is likely to be hers (if she has a boy and it is taken away, then a boy brought back at random is hers 1/4 times)

Comment: @Cato I had read the "There are $3$ boys and $x$ girls in a hospital"  as being the position after the birth.  But I now see there is an alternative reading which comes to your $\frac17$ - so I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

With the new information, I made a correction. Also, I added a rather philosophical argument, at the end.

Firstly, the experiment is to take a baby from $4+x$ babies, at random.

$P(B)$ is the probability that a picked baby is a boy. Therefore,

$$P(B)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{4+x}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4+x}=\frac{7}{2(4+x)}$$

$P(M)$ is the probability that a picked baby belongs to the mother. Therefore

$$P(M)=\frac{1}{4+x}$$

For $P(B|M)$, which is the probability that a picked baby is a boy, when we know that it belongs to the mother, we need to look at it from the mother point of view. She knows that it would be fifty-fifty. Therefore,

$$P(B|M)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Then you just need to use Bayes theorem to calculate

$$P(M|B)=\frac{1}{7}$$

**Extension:**

Bayesian approach is used when something cannot be measured, using frequentist approach. This problem is a good example. Assume we make the baby, that belongs to the mother, blue and we put a patch on it, so the gender is not observable. If we want to calculate $P(M|B)$, using frequencies, then we have to separate boys and do the following. Take one of the boys at random and show him to the mother. We need to do it many times and Mother would calculate the probability. But, in order to do such a thing, we need to know if the blue baby belongs to boys or not. So, the scenario is not well-defined and therefore, not accurately measurable.
That is why we resort to Bayesian approach and calculate things that we can more reliably approximate, like the the $P(M)$, $P(B)$ and combine it with a mere guess of $P(B|M)=0.5$.

Comment: If the mother knows about the babies in the baby room, I do not see how $\frac12$ can continue to be her best estimate.  If she does not know, then it cannot be combined with the other information

Comment: @Henry, I get your point and I think it is an interesting and fundamental issue. I think with Bayesian approach one needs to be careful with the point of view. I mean, From whose point of view we are looking at the problem. If we knew the underlying statistical model of the problem, under investigation, then we would never have needed the Bayesian approach. The statistical model, in this problem, is the number babies in the room. Mother is not supposed to know about the babies in the room.

Comment: in half the cases, it isn't her baby, because she had a girl.  In that case there was a 3/(x + 3) chance of seeing a boy.  If she had a boy, there was a 4/(x+4) chance she was shown a boy, and a 1/4 chance it is her boy - that doesn't mean the chances the boy is hers is 1/8, because there is a 3:4 ratio between the frequency of the cases - I get 1/7 as the chance it is hers

Comment: @Cato, you are right. $1/7$ is the right answer, I suppose

Comment: It seemed impossible at first, I was thinking about it in a meeting, and I realised that there are 6 cases where you see the 3 boys, and one where you see her boy

Answer (score 0):

P(handed her child | child handed over is boy) = P(handed her baby boy AND baby handed over was boy) / P( baby handed over was boy)

= $[\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{x + 4}] / [ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac {3}{x + 4} + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{x + 4}$]

$= \frac{1}{7}$

I think it is independent of x, the number of female babies - the mother has already had a boy or a girl, so it is boy with probability 1/2, in which case there would be 4 equally likely circumstances she would be handed a boy, one of which is hers - if it was a girl she had, she can be shown 3 equally likely boys not hers.

Another way of looking at it is that she has given birth to half a boy, to add to the 3 boys $\frac{\frac{1}{2} }{3 \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{7}$

So that's my answer, the chances the mother is looking at her baby is 1/7